# Pandas groupby .all method

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand how to use .all, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user_id": [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
    "score":   [1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,5,6,7,8]
})
```

When I try:

```
df.groupby("user_id").all(lambda x: x["score"] > 2)
```

I get:

```
         score
user_id       
1         True
2         True
3         True
```

But I expect:

```
         score
user_id       
1         False  # Since for first group of users the score is not greater than 2 for all
2         True
3         True
```

In fact it doesn't even matter what value I pass instead of 2, the result DataFrame always has `True` for the score column.

Why do I get the result that I get? How can I get my expected result?

I looked at the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html, but it is very brief and did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`groupby.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) does not take any function as parameter. The only parameter (`skipna`) accepts a boolean and is used to change how NaN values are interpreted.

You probably want:

```
df['score'].gt(2).groupby(df['user_id']).all()
```

Which can also be written as:

```
df.assign(flag=df['score'].gt(2)).groupby('user_id')['flag'].all()
```

Answer (score 2):

the line

```
df.groupby("user_id").all(lambda x: x["score"] > 2)
```

is not asking "are all datapoints larger than 2?", in reality is asking "are there datapoints?"

to ask what you really want you need to do the following:

```
df['score'].gt(2).groupby(df['user_id']).all()

Out

user_id
1    False
2     True
3     True
```